# ONVIF implementation in Yocto

Tags: video-streaming, yocto, onvif

I am looking if there's anybody that implemented ONVIF in Yocto devices, and the way it was done. Any info about it, it will be really appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Sorry for being negative... but this might not be the best place for this question: please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic.

Answer (score 0):

Yocto [supports gsoap](https://git.congatec.com/yocto/meta-openembedded/tree/aa205514421045517a07e0e57437dbad59b6a524/meta-oe/recipes-support/gsoap), thus you can iether integrate gsoap in your project build or can generate the files offline and manually add the gsoap library to your software.

Both ways are doable.